# Java: Check to see if String.contains matches exact word

Tags: java

Trying to check if a text file contains a string, however i just want the exact string, for example.

> String.contains(CA).

But lets say the text file

1. CA CALIFORNIA
2. NP CALIPER
3. WX ABDICATE

What would be the best method to just check for "CA" exactly, i only want to return true for (1), but in my case i'll get true for all three.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(Source)) {
            hasSource = true;
            break;
        }
        lineCounter++;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `startWith("CA")`?

Comment: you could split the original string on WHITE SPACE then check each sub part for "CA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try regex:

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\bCA\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = re.matcher(text);
```

[Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: But if my String has sentence like "new12.5, new12.0 , new.12" .Now i want to check if whole word new12.5 is present or not . How to check?.Because \\b check the character in front and last.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to find the string in another string, or you can even use this approach:

```
//let's assume words are seperated by spaces only
for(String word: line.split(" ")) {
    if(word.trim().equals(source))
    //add your functionality
}
```

This is assuming the word you want to search can appear anywhere in the line.